# Error in Wmi-Activity event log when using Win32_ProcessStartTrace from C#

Tags: c#, wmi

I am using Win32_ProcessStartTrace (and stop trace) as follows

```
m_ProcessStartEvent = new ManagementEventWatcher(m_Scope, new EventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
m_ProcessStartEvent.EventArrived += ProcessStartEvent_EventArrived;
m_ProcessStartEvent.Start();

...

m_ProcessStartEvent.Stop();
m_ProcessStartEvent.EventArrived -= ProcessStartEvent_EventArrived;
m_ProcessStartEvent.Dispose();
```

In the event log: Application and service Logs => Micorosft => windows => Wmi-Activity => Operational, I have the error

```
    System 
  - Provider 
   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity 
   [ Guid]  {1418EF04-B0B4-4623-BF7E-D74AB47BBDAA} 
   EventID 5858 
   Version 0 
   Level 2 
   Task 0 
   Opcode 0 
   Keywords 0x4000000000000000 
  - TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2018-12-10T09:48:49.189515600Z 
   EventRecordID 161732 
  - Correlation 
   [ ActivityID]  {73689ED9-87E0-0005-48B2-8073E087D401} 
  - Execution 
   [ ProcessID]  2532 
   [ ThreadID]  9116 
   Channel Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity/Operational 
   Computer ...
  - Security 
   [ UserID]  S-1-5-18 
- UserData 
  - Operation_ClientFailure 
   Id {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 
   ClientMachine ...
   User ...
   ClientProcessId 38256 
   Component Unknown 
   Operation Start IWbemServices::ExecNotificationQuery - root\cimv2 : SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace 
   ResultCode 0x80041032 
   PossibleCause Unknown
```

Any ideas what is causing it and how to resolve it?

I do see

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3124914/wmi-activity-event-5858-logged-frequently-with-resultcode-0x80041032

but I don't understand if this is relevant and if so, what to do about it.

Thanks,

Comment: That is WBEM_E_CALL_CANCELLED, it doesn't have to indicate anything nasty.  Could be the service provider falling over, that would be bad and you'd expect to see additional events, but it is also recorded when your program terminates the query.  Just check if the event log entry corresponds with your program calling Stop().

Answer (score 0):

For my situation on a windows 7 system it was a file in System32\DRIVERS\vdbus.sys left by comodo. Deleted it and my wmi activity errors went away.